# Optaplanner benchmarkAggregator can run with benchmark simultaneously?

Tags: optaplanner

I did run the bench marking successfully without aggregator, and I did run the aggregator alone.

Can I run the bench marking and obtain the aggregator gui simultaneously?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The benchmarker outputs a report - if you want to filter that with the aggregator, why not filter the original benchmark config?

Comment: I just want to use all the capabilities of the Optaplanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just write a `main()` that does both in sequence:

```
    PlannerBenchmarkFactory plannerBenchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(
            "org/optaplanner/examples/nqueens/benchmark/nqueensBenchmarkConfig.xml");
    PlannerBenchmark plannerBenchmark = benchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark();
    plannerBenchmark.benchmark();
    PlannerBenchmarkFactory plannerBenchmarkFactory2 = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(
            "org/optaplanner/examples/nqueens/benchmark/nqueensBenchmarkConfig.xml");
    BenchmarkAggregatorFrame.createAndDisplay(plannerBenchmarkFactory2);
```

Comment: I have CommonBenchmarkApp the same as the one in the examples, and MyProblemApp is as follows:

            public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MaxGainBenchmarkApp().buildAndBenchmark(args);
    }

    public MaxGainBenchmarkApp() {
        super(
                new ArgOption("default",
                        "org/optaplanner/examples/customertask/benchmark/maxGainBenchmarkConfig.xml") );}

Comment: How can I insert what you tell me to do in such case?

Comment: CommonBenchmarkApp is part of the examples, it's not part of our feature set.